# Should you scale numeric categorical feature in tree based models?

Tags: random-forest, scaling, xgboost, categorical-data

I am scaling data for tree based classifiers which I know is not necessary (but also shouldn't hurt). Most my features are quantitative but I also have "day_of_week" which I have left as 0-6 (not dummied). Is it proper to scale this feature? Or should I hold it out of scaling and add it back into after scaling is done? Or should this be in dummy format? Or should I skip scaling completely?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Tree based approaches are insensitive to the scale of the data and are purely based on the order, so there is no need to scale your data.